# How to solve this trigonometric system?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

Namely,

$$\left\{\left(\tan ^2\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)+\tan ^2\left(y+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right) (\sin (x)+\cos (y)-1)=0,\\
(\sin (y)-\sin (2 y)+2) (\sin (x)-\cos (y))=0,\\x\geq 0,x<2 \pi ,y\geq 0,y<2 \pi \right\}. $$

The plot

```
ContourPlot[{(Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1)*(Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2) ==0, 
(Sin[x] - Cos[y])*(2 - Sin[2 y] + Sin[y]) == 0}, {x,0,2*Pi}, {y, 0,2*Pi}]
```

[image]

shows four real solutions. However,

```
Reduce[{(Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1)*(Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2) == 0, 
(Sin[x] -Cos[y])*(2 - Sin[2 y] + Sin[y])==0,x >= 0, x<2*Pi, y >= 0, y < 2*Pi},{x,y}, Reals]
```

performs

> (x == [Pi]/6 && 
>      y == (5 [Pi])/3) || (x == 
>       2 ([Pi] + 
>          ArcTan[Root[{-3 + #1^2 &, 
>             9 + 24 #1 #2 + 168 #2^2 + 440 #1 #2^3 - 1604 #2^4 - 
>               4968 #1 #2^5 + 8600 #2^6 + 11000 #1 #2^7 - 12042 #2^8 - 
>               11000 #1 #2^9 + 8600 #2^10 + 4968 #1 #2^11 - 1604 #2^12 - 
>               440 #1 #2^13 + 168 #2^14 - 24 #1 #2^15 + 9 #2^16 &}, {2, 
>             2}]]) && 
>      y == 2 ArcTan[
>         Root[{-3 + #1^2 &, 
>           9 + 24 #1 #2 + 168 #2^2 + 440 #1 #2^3 - 1604 #2^4 - 
>             4968 #1 #2^5 + 8600 #2^6 + 11000 #1 #2^7 - 12042 #2^8 - 
>             11000 #1 #2^9 + 8600 #2^10 + 4968 #1 #2^11 - 1604 #2^12 - 
>             440 #1 #2^13 + 168 #2^14 - 24 #1 #2^15 + 9 #2^16 &, 
>           31716 + 23256 #1 + 129132 #2 - 9873 #1 #2 + 3554904 #2^2 + 
>             447978 #1 #2^2 - 3706428 #2^3 + 15729 #1 #2^3 - 
>             23650076 #2^4 - 4305612 #1 #2^4 + 11333348 #2^5 + 
>             7026787 #1 #2^5 + 46524792 #2^6 + 8877606 #1 #2^6 - 
>             12884532 #2^7 - 11758723 #1 #2^7 - 44195412 #2^8 - 
>             8512688 #1 #2^8 + 7284948 #2^9 + 9579965 #1 #2^9 + 
>             19350440 #2^10 + 3611158 #1 #2^10 - 1247492 #2^11 - 
>             1925981 #1 #2^11 - 1720692 #2^12 - 307100 #1 #2^12 + 
>             116700 #2^13 + 219825 #1 #2^13 - 93816 #2^14 - 
>             16998 #1 #2^14 + 6516 #2^15 + 11439 #1 #2^15 + 
>             147456 #3 &}, {2, 2, 1}]]) || (x == 
>       2 ArcTan[
>         Root[{-3 + #1^2 &, 
>           9 + 24 #1 #2 + 168 #2^2 + 440 #1 #2^3 - 1604 #2^4 - 
>             4968 #1 #2^5 + 8600 #2^6 + 11000 #1 #2^7 - 12042 #2^8 - 
>             11000 #1 #2^9 + 8600 #2^10 + 4968 #1 #2^11 - 1604 #2^12 - 
>             440 #1 #2^13 + 168 #2^14 - 24 #1 #2^15 + 9 #2^16 &}, {2, 
>           6}]] && y == 
>       2 [Pi] + 
>        2 ArcTan[
>          Root[{-3 + #1^2 &, 
>            9 + 24 #1 #2 + 168 #2^2 + 440 #1 #2^3 - 1604 #2^4 - 
>              4968 #1 #2^5 + 8600 #2^6 + 11000 #1 #2^7 - 12042 #2^8 - 
>              11000 #1 #2^9 + 8600 #2^10 + 4968 #1 #2^11 - 1604 #2^12 - 
>              440 #1 #2^13 + 168 #2^14 - 24 #1 #2^15 + 9 #2^16 &, 
>            31716 + 23256 #1 + 129132 #2 - 9873 #1 #2 + 3554904 #2^2 + 
>              447978 #1 #2^2 - 3706428 #2^3 + 15729 #1 #2^3 - 
>              23650076 #2^4 - 4305612 #1 #2^4 + 11333348 #2^5 + 
>              7026787 #1 #2^5 + 46524792 #2^6 + 8877606 #1 #2^6 - 
>              12884532 #2^7 - 11758723 #1 #2^7 - 44195412 #2^8 - 
>              8512688 #1 #2^8 + 7284948 #2^9 + 9579965 #1 #2^9 + 
>              19350440 #2^10 + 3611158 #1 #2^10 - 1247492 #2^11 - 
>              1925981 #1 #2^11 - 1720692 #2^12 - 307100 #1 #2^12 + 
>              116700 #2^13 + 219825 #1 #2^13 - 93816 #2^14 - 
>              16998 #1 #2^14 + 6516 #2^15 + 11439 #1 #2^15 + 
>              147456 #3 &}, {2, 6, 1}]])

which is not correct in view of

```
N[%]
```

> (x==0.523599&&y==5.23599)||(x==4.18879&&y==2.61799)||(x==1.0472&&y==5.75959)

and

```
{(Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1)*(Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2) ==  0, 
(Sin[x] - Cos[y])*(2 - Sin[2 y] + Sin[y]) == 0} /. 
{x -> 4.188790204786391, y -> 2.6179938779914944}
```

> {False,False}

Addition. Up to the suggestion of Michael E2, the command

```
Reduce[{(Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1)*(Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2) == 
0, (Sin[x] - Cos[y])*(2 - Sin[2 y] + Sin[y]) == 0, x>= 0, x < 2*Pi, y>= 0, y < 2*Pi}, {x, y}, Reals]//FullSimplify
```

does the job, outputting

> 6 x == [Pi] && 3 y == 5 [Pi]) || (3 x == 4 [Pi] && 
>      6 y == 5 [Pi]) || (3 x == [Pi] && 6 y == 11 [Pi])

Micael E2 also explains the result of `ContourPlot` in his comments.

The happy end.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78331/discussion-on-question-by-user64494-how-to-solve-this-trigonometric-system).

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is that by searching for roots of `(Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1) (Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2)`, we happen to have a root of the first factor where the second factor has a singularity. I am also not happy my the behavior of `Reduce` but I can understand that this is a delicate case.

Replacing the product by an `Or` (`||`) can serve as a somewhat dirty workaround:

```
eqn = {(Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1)*(Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2) == 
    0, (Sin[x] - Cos[y])*(2 - Sin[2 y] + Sin[y]) == 0};
eqn1 = {
  (Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1) == 0 || (Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2) == 0,
  (Sin[x] - Cos[y]) (2 - Sin[2 y] + Sin[y]) == 0, 
  0 <= x < 2 Pi, 
  0 <= y < 2 Pi
}; 
Reduce[eqn1, {x, y}] // RootReduce; 
sol = Solve[eqn1, {x, y}, Method -> Reduce]; 

pts = {x, y, 0} /. sol; 
Show[
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[#, 0.2] & /@ pts}], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate@{eqn[[1, 1]], eqn[[2, 1]], 0}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, {y, 0, 
   2*Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}
  ],
 Axes -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Note also that two of the solution points do not appear in the contour plot because they are isolated roots of the first equation and thus hardly detectable by `CountourPlot`. (In the picture above, you see crossings of only green and blue or of only blue and yellow at these points.)

**Let me recapitulate the discussion:**

(1)
OP complains that the solutions obtained from

```
f = (Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1)*(Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2);
g = (Sin[x] - Cos[y])*(2 - Sin[2 y] + Sin[y]);
cond = {f == 0, g == 0, x >= 0, x < 2*Pi, y >= 0, y < 2*Pi};
sol0 = Reduce[cond, {x, y}, Reals];
```

were wrong. But they aren't:

```
{f, g} /. Solve[sol0, {x, y}] // N
```

> {{0., 0.}, {-1.33166*10^-31, 1.12111*10^-15}, {4.66608*10^-32, 
>     5.25363*10^-16}}

So the solutions are correct up to machine precision (and that only because `N` was used). In fact, one could also use

```
{f, g} /. RootReduce[Solve[sol0, {x, y}]]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}

(2) After getting this as feedback, OP complains in a comment that they want to have more roots ("more than four items").

But that enforces us to stretch the meaning of a solution and to include some extra solutions. [mathe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5379/mathe) came up with the nice idea to use

```
sol = Solve[{Reduce[cond[[1 ;; 2]]], 0 <= x < 2 Pi, 0 <= y < 2 Pi}, {x, y}] // RootReduce;
```

Summarized this looks like this:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@Join[{cond[[1 ;; 2]], y == Pi/3, x == 5/6 Pi}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}],
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{x, y} /. sol], Gray, 
   Point[{x, y} /. RootReduce[Solve[sol0, {x, y}]]]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Here the blue and yellow lines represent the zero-sets of `f` and `g` respectively, while the green and red line represent (a part of) the singular set of `f`. The three gray points are the three solutions from the beginning; the three black points came basically from the continuation of the zero-sets.

(3) OP complains that also the black points appear (although this was quite exactly what they asked for), downvotes and sends us back to high school.

If you ask me, something is really fishy about this procedure...

Comment: Thank you. You see the heart of the problem. However, I don't see a solution of the problem. Its solution by hand is not so hard.

Comment: In what sense does this not solve the problem? Would you please be a bit more specific? The equation you have posted has precisely these six solutions.

Comment: You solved the system which is not equivalent to the fomulated one: eqn /. sol[[1]] outputs {Indeterminate, 0}. The same issue with sol[[3]] and sol[[4]]. In fact you repeat the answer by @mathe.

Comment: The system _is_ equivalent to the orginal one. We just copied it from your post. _Your means to check the solutions_ have flaws. `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) cannot compute limits. For example, compare `ReplaceAll[Sin[x]/x /. x -> 0]` and `Limit[Sin[x]/x, x -> 0]`. That's why I proposed to check your solutions with `Reduce[eqn] /. sol` instead. It returns `{True, True, True, True, True, True}`.

Comment: Up to school  math the points $\{x= {\it arbitrary\, real \,number}, y =\frac \pi 3 \}$ do not belong to the domain of the system.

Comment: No need to get patronizing towards people who spend their free time to help you. I'm done here.

Answer (score 7):

I think this may be a bug with `Reduce`, but this works

```
eqn={(Cos[y]+Sin[x]-1) (Tan[x-Pi/3]^2+Tan[y+Pi/6]^2)==0,
     (Sin[x]-Cos[y]) (2-Sin[2 y]+Sin[y])==0};

sol=Solve[{Reduce[eqn],0<=x<2Pi,0<=y<2Pi},{x,y}]//RootReduce

ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqn],{x,0,2Pi},{y,0,2Pi},Epilog->{PointSize@Medium,Point[{x,y}/.sol]}]
```

> {{x->π/6,y->π/3},{x->π/6,y->(5 π)/3},{x->π/3,y->(11 π)/6},{x->(5 π)/6,y->π/3},{x->(5 π)/6,y->(5 π)/3},{x->(4 π)/3,y->(5 π)/6}}

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the command eqn/.sol[[1]] performs {Indeterminate == 0, True}. The same with sol[[4]] and sol[[5]]. -1 still is mine.

Comment: @user64494 You are somewhat pushy, aren't you? Try `Reduce[eqn] /. sol `. I suggest to accept mathe's answer; it settles your original question as well as several follow-up questions.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Sorry, I can't accept the solution of a different problem which is not equivalent to the fomulated one.

Comment: @user64494 In what sense does this not solve the problem? Would you please be a bit more specific? The equation you have posted has precisely these six solutions

Comment: Up to school math the points $\{ x={\it arbitrary\,real\,number},y=\pi /3 \} $ do not belong to the domain of the system. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Three of your solutions are correct. But at the two points where `x = 5 Pi/6`, `Tan[x - Pi/3]` is undefined. At the two lower points where `y = Pi/3`, `Tan[y + Pi/6]` is undefined.  Therefore they are not solutions. If you enlarge the plot and omit the points, you'll see gaps at three of the points that indicate some sort of discontinuity, which corresponds to the points I indicated.

Answer (score 2):

With some `ConditionalExpression` we found:

```
eqn = {(Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1) (Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2) == 0 && 
       (Sin[x] - Cos[y]) (2 - Sin[2 y] + Sin[y]) == 0};

sol = {x, y} /. N[Solve[{Reduce[eqn], 0 <= x < 2 Pi, 0 <= y < 2 Pi}, {x, y}]]
pts = sol[[1 ;; 4]];

ContourPlot[
  {(Cos[y] + Sin[x] - 1)*(Tan[x - Pi/3]^2 + Tan[y + Pi/6]^2) == 0,
   (Sin[x] - Cos[y])*(2 - Sin[2 y] + Sin[y]) == 0}, 
  {x, 0, 2*Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: At the two points on the right, `x = 5 Pi/6` and `Tan[x - Pi/3]` is undefined. At the two lower points, `y = Pi/3` and `Tan[y + Pi/6]` is undefined.  Therefore they are not solutions despite what the plot appears to show.